# TableColumn.setGraphic underneath the Column label

Tags: javafx, tableview

When I use the following code to add a TextField to each column:

```
      tableColumn.setGraphic(textField);
```

The textfield gets placed on the left side of the label, making the columns look like this:

[image]

If I drag the column width out, I see that the label is still there

[image]

Is there any way to make the Column use it's original label, and place the textfield underneath?
I have tried with adding my own label in a VBox together with the textfield, but then you loose the auto width functionality.

After James_D's answer, the label is correct, but the column style is still a bit strange?

[image]

MVCE:

```
public class TableViewTEST extends Application {

List<TableColumn> listOfColumns = new ArrayList();
TableView tableView = new TableView();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}


public void buildData() {

    TableColumn myColumn = new TableColumn("asd");
    TableColumn myColumn2 = new TableColumn("qq");
    listOfColumns.add(myColumn);
    listOfColumns.add(myColumn2);
    //add columns dynamically
    int counter = 0;
    for (TableColumn col : listOfColumns) {
        final int j = counter;

  col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MyTableRow, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MyTableRow, String> param) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().rowData.get(j));

            }
        });

        counter++;
        TextField txtField = new TextField();
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(txtField);
        col.setGraphic(vbox);
        tableView.getColumns().add(col);

    }

    tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {

        MyTableRow rowz = new MyTableRow();

        rowz.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!rowz.isEmpty())) {

            }
        });

        return rowz;

    });

}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FlowPane flowpane = new FlowPane();
    flowpane.getChildren().add(tableView);

    buildData();
    Scene scene = new Scene(flowpane);

    scene.getStylesheets().add(TableViewTEST.class.getResource("css.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an external css file with the following:

```
.table-column .label {
    -fx-content-display: bottom ;
}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithTextFieldColumnHeaders extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<List<String>> table = new TableView<>();

        table.getColumns().add( createColumn("A", 0) );
        table.getColumns().add( createColumn("B", 1) );

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("table-text-field.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn<List<String>, String> createColumn(String title, int index) {

        TableColumn<List<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);

        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
            new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().get(index)));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        col.setGraphic(textField);

        double textFieldPadding = 8 ;
        textField.prefWidthProperty().bind(
                col.widthProperty().subtract(textFieldPadding));

        return col ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with the css file table-text-field.css:

```
.table-column .label {
    -fx-content-display: bottom ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @james_D

But still, the formatting of the column looks pretty strange? I'll update my question

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Maybe experiment with the min/prefWidth properties of the text field and column.

Comment: But they will always vary dependent on the user data

Comment: I guess I was envisioning using bindings. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the behavior in your screenshot?

Comment: That's not an MCVE, I cannot compile it.

Comment: It probably fails because of the line where I add a css... but without that you can't test the example. Just create a empty CSS with the code you added in your answer?

Comment: It refers to two classes for which you don't provide the code. Anyway, it is not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please create a *minimal* example *from scratch* that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see that. Thank you!